# How do I programatically change datagrid row color in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, background-color

I was wondering if this possible. I have this datagrid contains 3 columns and 2 rows. What I want is to change the background of the URL column on my datagrid according to the data I enter.

Here is sample of my xaml code:

```
<DataGrid
    x:Name="mylistview"
    BorderBrush="#FF373737"
    Background="Black"
    VerticalGridLinesBrush="#FF232323"
    HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FF212121">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="URL" Foreground="{Binding rowColor}" Binding="{Binding url}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Version" Foreground="White" Binding="{Binding version}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Valid" Foreground="White" Binding="{Binding valid}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

My class used to fill up the datagrid with rows:

```
public class myData
{
    public string url {get; set;}
    public string version{get; set;}
    public string valid{get; set;}

    //this should be the value that changes the bg color 
    public string rowColor{ get; set; }
}
```

And here is my way to add rows to the control:

```
 myData data1 = new myData();
 data1.url = "http://google.com";
 data1.valid = "yes";
 data1.version = "1";
 data1.rowColor = "#FF000000";
 this.mylistview.Items.Add(data1);

 data1.url = "http://yahoo.com";
 data1.valid = "no";
 data1.version = "1";
 data1.rowColor = "#000000FF";
 this.mylistview.Items.Add(data1);
```

I have two elements. Each row should have its own color. The first one should be red
and the second one should be blue. I really don't know how to make the control use the rowColor value.

What do I need to do to get this working?

Answer (score 3):

Your `rowColor` should not return a string (i would rename it to `RowColor` since it is public), just return the actual colour-brushes instead. (Your colours are wrong by the way, the first is opaque black and the second is transparent blue)

e.g.

```
public Brush rowColor { get; set; }
```

```
data1.rowColor = Brushes.Red;
data2.rowColor = Brushes.Blue;
```

If you really need to parse from string you could use a [value converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) or the standard conversion that is used when parsing Xaml.

Besides that i am not sure if binding those properties to `Foreground` of the column will work.